Android Studio onDraw() can't trigger by invalidate()
I Have two view (.java)that called A view and B view,my main goal is to trigger B view's onDraw() from A view. After I run BviewInstance.invalidate() in A view,I can only trigger A view's.
I had tried my best,and didn't find the answer in the web, hope someone can help me figured out!
public class AView extends View {
    private BView B_view;

    public AView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);
    B_view = new BView(context, attrs); ...
    }     ...  

    B_view.changeBviewData();
    B_view.Invalidate();
    ...
}

xml:
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">


    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraview"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hotSpot_imgV"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/hotspot_preview" />

        <com.tencent.yolov8ncnn.BView
            android:id="@+id/BView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />



    </FrameLayout>




    <com.tencent.yolov8ncnn.AView
        android:id="@+id/AView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


</FrameLayout>

It only trigger AView ondraw()
